# Trying in Python to get a loop running with several if statments

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm learning Python and I'm lost atm :

```
from random import randint

x = 10

y = 4

hit = randint(1,100)

while x > 0:

    if hit >= 50:

        print "you hit for %d" % y
        x -= y

    elif hit < 50:

        print "you miss"
```

What I'm tryng to do is get a loop going that every time runs a "new" if I hit or if I miss untill x = 0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you have your `x -=y` only in one of the conditional branches, that means if `hit < 50` `x-=y` will never get run, which will cause an infinite loop, you need to change it to:

```
while x > 0:
    hit = randint(1,100)

    if hit >= 50:
        print "you hit for %d" % y

    elif hit < 50:
        print "you miss"
    x -= y
```

you also had your `randint` outside of the loop, so `hit` would have always been the same value.
Looking at your code again, `x` seems to be hp, and the loop will end when hp is depleted, so your `x-=y` is fine in that case.

Comment: Thanks every one. Really helping me out here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a different random number each time through the loop, put the random number generation inside the loop. Move `hit = randint(1,100)` between the `while x > 0:` and the `if hit >= 50:`.

Answer (score 0):

If `hit` is declared outside of the loop, the value will stay the same forever, either ending the program after three times around the loop or never ending. It must be this:

```
while x > 0:
    hit = random.randint(1,100)
    if hit >= 50:
        print "You hit for %d" % y
        x -= y
    elif hit < 50:
        print "You missed"
```

Although it is not necessary, because a random integer from 1 to 100 is either < or >= 50, it is good to get in the habit of defensive programming, so maybe put in this little else statement:

```
    else:
        print "Error, something is wrong"
```